# how to use Verilog mode AUTOINST?

Tags: emacs, verilog

I'm trying to use AUTOINST.
my problem is that Module name is different from the it's verilog file name (located under subdir) so the following won't work:

```
module ExampInout (o,i);
  InstModule instName
  (/*AUTOINST*/);
endmodule

// Local Variables:
// verilog-library-directories:("subdir")
// End:
```

How can I let verilog mode "know" that InstModule reside under subdir but in file other than InstModule.v?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about [this Emacs plugin](https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode)?

Comment: The bigger question is why the filename and module names do not match?

Answer (score 1):

[verilog-library-files](https://www.veripool.org/projects/verilog-mode/wiki/Verilog-mode-Help#verilog-library-files) is what you're looking for.  You can specify a full or relative path to each file in the list.

That said the comment on the question is a good one.  Good style is usually to have the module name match the file name.  The exception to this is when it's a 'library' file that contains lots of small module definitions.